# Inno Setup .net Framework Autoinstaller Issue

Tags: .net, installation, inno-setup

Im trying to check and download .net framework if it is not already installed 
Im following http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/NET-Framework-1-1-2-0-3-5-Installer-for-InnoSetup

The project works fine,in win 7.But in windows xp with internet explorer 6.This error opens up

[image]

As mentioned in the project page,there are some issues in case of IE6.What is the reason for this error and is there a way to solve this.

Plus i expect that almost all users using XP will have a newer version of windows explorer(if this error occurs due to old IE Version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is there is problem with WIC or Windows Installer not IE6.

.net Framework may use some components from IE but there is many other stuff to check.

Simply open the .iss file and read the dependencies at header, e.g.:

**.NET Framework 2.0** (dotnetfx20.iss)

```
// requires Windows 2000 Service Pack 3, Windows 98, Windows 98 Second Edition, Windows ME, Windows Server 2003, Windows XP Service Pack 2
// requires internet explorer 5.0.1 or higher
// requires windows installer 2.0 on windows 98, ME
// requires Windows Installer 3.1 on windows 2000 or higher
// http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0856eacb-4362-4b0d-8edd-aab15c5e04f5
```

So you need to check whether all dependencies are satisfied - e.g. for **Windows Installer 3.1** check file msi31.iss (again inside it there may be other dependencies) and check whether it was installed succesfully.

You need to have all dependencies installed correctly to install .net Framework correctly!

Comment: Thanks.But i remember installing .Net Framework on the same pc manually(4.0 full).But i had used the offline installer,not the installer which downloads the files.This project uses the online installer.I think using the offline installer will work.what do you think

Comment: I also checked MSI Version its 3.01